# How do I call Dom.transform on an element without an ID?

Tags: opa

I've been trying to expand on the hello_chat application. I wanted to replace the contents of the "body" tag, but can't seem to find a method for doing so. I assumed `Dom.transform([Dom.select_body <- content])` would do the trick, but was apparently mistaken. In the end I just created a div with the ID "everything" to wrap the page, but the question is still bugging me.

How would I do a transformation on the "body" tag? Is it possible? Even better, is there any way to use CSS selectors to do transformations on one or many elements at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First simple solution :

```
Dom.transform([#Body <- content])
```

Opa adds an id 'Body' to the `<body>`.

Second solution :

```
do Dom.transform([{Dom.select_body()} <- content])
```

Notice the **curly brackets** around the Dom.select_XXX, and the function call
http://doc.opalang.org/api/index.html#dom.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.xhtml.Dom.select_body

Third solution :

```
d = Dom.select_raw("body") // jQuery selector
do Dom.transform([{d} <- content])
```

You can also use raw CSS selector :)
http://doc.opalang.org/api/index.html#dom.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.xhtml.Dom.select_raw

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know about the necessity of the curly brackets. Is there a place in the documentation where the curly brackets are more fully explained?

Thanks!